# How do I correctly find a value in an object from an array, by matching it to another array with the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

So I have an array of values which I need to find:

```
const values = [ 'v4', 'w1']
```

And there is the array of objects where I need to look into:

```
const nodes = [
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And I basically need to find which is the node that matches the values array (in this example, the result should be `nodes[6]`

```
{
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

`values` array will always have the length of `node.options`, but one of the values can be `undefined` in which case the first occurrence of the defined value should be returned.

e.g. `values = [ undefined, 'w1']` -> `nodes[0]`

I managed to do something like

```
const result = nodes.find(
        (node) =>
          options[0].value === values[0] &&
          options[1].value === values[1]
      );
```

But his won't work if options has length different than 2.

Some other things I tried: (but seem to no be working)

```
nodes.find((node) => node.options.find(item => {
        values.map(opt => opt === item.value)
      }))

nodes.find((node) => node.options.filter(item => {
    return values.includes(item.value)
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

To found node that have option in values array you can do something like

```
 var found = nodes.filter(elem => {
      return !elem.node.options.some(option => 
          !values.some(value => option.value === value)
      );
    });
```

- **filter** to get only element that match condition
- **some** to check if element are in values array

```js
const values = [ 'v4', 'w1'];

const nodes = [
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
];

var found = nodes.filter(elem => {
  return !elem.node.options.some(option => 
      !values.some(value => option.value === value)
  );
});

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operators can be used to achieve the solution.

1. Iterate over the array elements to `find` the matching element.
2. Use `reduce` and `spread` to convert each element's `options` to an array of corresponding `optionValues`.
3. The current element is a match if `optionValues` match `values`. (Using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is one of the many ways to compare two arrays).

Something like this :

```js
const nodes = [
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Key1",
                    "value": "v5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Key2",
                    "value": "w2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
];

const values = [
    "v4",
    "w1"
];

const getOptionValues = options => {
  return options.reduce((vals, curOption) => {
    vals = [...vals, curOption.value];
    return vals;
  }, []);
}

const matchingNode = nodes.find(ele => {
  const optionValues = getOptionValues(ele.node.options);
  return JSON.stringify(values) === JSON.stringify(optionValues);
});

console.log(matchingNode);
```